# Select sublist from a list where sublist's item has minimum difference from a given value

Tags: python

I'm using `python v2.7` and I have the parameter `mean_val=35.3085666667`
I have a list `new_add_list` that contains sublists. In `new_add_list[3]` I have a score value. From `new_add_list` I want to get the sublist that has the minimun value of `abs(new_add_list[3]-mean_val)`.

```
new_add_list=[
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_192x144_15_qp_26_ON_encoder_randomaccess_B16_Filte
rs_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', '192x144', 26, 35.1782, 136.8125, 300.788, 0.844, -3.5], 
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_15_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_
B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', '384x288', 28, 35.2193, 275.4614, 1065.412, 2.167, -2], 
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_720x576_15_qp_30_ON_encoder_rando
maccess_B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', '720x576', 30, 35.5282, 484.3387, 3536.937, 6.679, 1.5]]
```

For that example the answer must be:

```
['encoding_txt\\pirkagia_10b_384x288_15_qp_28_ON_encoder_randomaccess_
B16_Filters_ON_scalable_JOURNAL2017.txt', '384x288', 28, 35.2193, 275.4614, 1065.412, 2.167, -2]
```

Can I use something like `sub(new_add_list, key=itemgetter(3)-mean_val)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) with an appropriate key function:

```
min(new_add_list, key=lambda l: abs(l[3] - mean_val))
```